# How to execute an action on viewController1 from a button on viewController2?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

So I have viewcontroller1 and I have one `UIScrollview` on it to make it move.  I have a `Home` button that when pressed moves the scrollView to a desired position.
That part works fine.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func home(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (scrollView != nil){
            scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(8, 1004, 359, 496), animated: true)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var scrollView2: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if (scrollView2 != nil){
            scrollView2.contentSize.height = 5000
            scrollView2.contentSize.width = 375
        }

        if (ScrollView != nil){
            scrollView.contentSize.height = 5000
            scrollView.contentSize.width = 375
        }

    }

}
```

I have a second view controller that is presented from the first with a `Push` segue.  This view controller also has a `UIButton` named `Home`.  When I click the `Home` button in viewController2, I want to return to viewController1 and execute the `home` action there to position the scrollView in viewController1.

How can I do this in Swift?  Thanks!

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking since the view controller structure is far from obvious - what has the scroll view to do with anything? Side note: variables and method names should be written in camel case: `scrollView` and `home`.

Comment: i have the home button linked to the scrollview so when i click home it goes to that spot but when i put home in a new ViewController which is ViewController2 then i would want it so when i tap home it goes to ViewController that was the initial view controller which is ViewController1 and then  scroll automatically to the x,y,w,h that i have put in

Comment: if you are using a `uinavigationcontroller`, call `popViewControllerAnimated:` - you give too little information about your current setup.

Comment: there i put all i have, will this be enough to help me out?

Comment: basically i need a button so when i push it, it will go to another ViewController to a Y spot of UIScrollVIew

Comment: SOMEBODY HELP OR TELL ME TO ADD MORE INFORMATION????

Comment: I still have no idea how you two controllers are connected and how you get / want to get from one to the other - **and fix your naming**

Comment: i have them connected by control-drag and show by push

Comment: i dont know what you mean by fix my naming

Comment: variable and method names should be written in camel case, starting with lower case letters - that will even fix the syntax highlighting on SO.

Comment: there i have put lower cases, can you tell me what you need and ill tell you

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where you learn how to make an app. Try youtube, blogs, books,... Come here when you have written code and it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: what do you think the above looks like smart guy, it didnt work out so now i need help

Comment: There is no code at all that has anything to do with going from one viewcontroller to another. Which means you have done no effort at all to learn how to do this.

Comment: if you control drag and click show it connects 2 viewcontrollers from storyboard, just answered your question. Try blogs??? Are you srs??? You know what a blog is?

Comment: stackoverflow is a place where you come to ask questions, if you need help, to LEARN, what do you think im doing?

Comment: NO EFFORT???? LMAO    i did put effort acually not like you would know of

Comment: is there any other thing you would like to say, im being nice but your not

Comment: I do put effort to learn, who said im not, im new to coding and im finding people who would help me. Fresh start, want to help me out?

Comment: You mentioned that you have your view controllers connected by "push". So  ```        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)``` should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to press the <kbd>Home</kbd> button in viewController2 and return to viewController1 and execute a method to position your scrollView.

You could use an *unwind segue* for this task.  Right below your `home` function in your initial viewController, add a method called `goHome`:

```
@IBAction func home(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (scrollView != nil) {
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(8, 1004, 359, 496), animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func goHome(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // Call the home method to position the scrollView
    home(self)
}
```

Then in the Storyboard, <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from the <kbd>Home</kbd> button in viewController2 to the `Exit` icon at the top of the viewController, and choose `goHome` from the popup.

---

[image: drag from home button to exit icon]

---

[image: select goHome from popup]

---

Then when you run your app and press <kbd>Home</kbd> in viewController2, it will unwind back to viewController1 and call `home` to position the scrollView where you want it.

Comment: Thanks alot I'll go practice this now.

Comment: i have one more question, in viewController2 i have a 'Back' UIButton'  connected to viewController1 so I can go back to it. Is it possible that when Im at a spot on the scrollView I can go to viewController2 and when I tap on back instead of the UIButtons I have set in viewController2 I go back to my original spot where I left off ? I know that part of going from viewController1 to 2 but don't know how to be at the original spot when I go viewController2 to 1. Thanks for helping me on the other part, I will practice that one

Comment: How is your back button connected?  Is it the default one that the Navigation Controller provides, or have you just added a `UIButton` called `Back` that uses a push segue to return to VC1?

Comment: just added a UIButton called Back that uses a push segue to return to VC1

Comment: You don't want to return to VC1 with a push segue.  A push segue creates a new copy of VC1. You want to use an unwind segue like I showed above.  Create a second landing spot `@IBAction func returnHere(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { // nothing to do here right now }` in VC1, and wire your `Back` button to Exit icon and select `returnHere`.  Then when you press `Back` you'll be back in VC1 *exactly* as you left it.

Comment: I have one more question, if I use a push segue and create a new copy of VC1, does it make a difference?

Comment: If you use a push segue, you get a new VC1 that doesn't look like the VC1 you left.  The other VC1 is still in memory, so if you kept this up, your app would eventually run out of memory and crash.  You should return to the VC1 you came from, not create a new one.

Comment: do you have an email I can message you on, not many people on here help me out when I get errors.

Comment: No.  I answer all questions on StackOverflow only.  That way, other people can see my answers which help them too.  That's the point of Stack Overflow.  If others aren't answering your questions, its because the questions are worded poorly.  Work to create clearly worded questions that only contain enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Did I word this poorly ? I have another question :)  I have VCMain connected with a push segue to VC1, and then you already know how VC1 connected with VC2 and then unwind segue for VC2 to go back. I tried the same for VC1 to go back to VCMain with unwind segue but it dose not do anything. That UIButton is also named as Back2 as an IBOutlet which is in VC1. I did the exact thing you told me for the first unwind,                                   @IBAction func returnBack(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
     
        
}           thats the one for VC1 to VCMain which dose not work.

Comment: No need to answer that i figured it out, i didn't make the VCMain under the class ViewController

Comment: I would say this question was worded poorly based upon the number of readers who wrote "it is unclear what you are asking".  I edited your original question and title heavily to make it clearer.

Comment: I guess I suck at asking questions then :)

Comment: Main.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: Interface Builder does not support UIView sizes larger than 10,000 by 10,000.   Is there a way i can do more than this instead of making another viewController?

Comment: how would i be able to go from any VC to the initial, like VC3 to VC1. When I do the unwind segue it only goes back 1 but all at the same time.